# how to vectorze this kind of loop for array

Tags: matlab

I'm newbie to Matlab. I have some questions.

How can I vectorise this loop:

```
epsilon = 0.45;
t = -3.033;
n = 100;
I = ones(n,n);
%// diagonal block 1
DB1 = gallery('tridiag',ones(1,n-1),ones(1,n),ones(1,n-1));
for k = 1:n
    DB1(k,k) = epsilon;
end
for k = 1:n-1
    DB1(k,k+1) = t*heaviside((-1)^(k+1));
end
for k = 2:n
    DB1(k,k-1) = t*heaviside((-1)^k);
```

and this loop with `LRG`, `R2`, `R1` are 3D arrays

```
for k = 2:N
    LRG(:,:,k) = inv(R(:,:,k) - R2(:,:,k-1)*LRG(:,:,k-1)*R1(:,:,k-1));
end
```

Is there any way to handle the third dimension of an array (page) without writing `(:,:,...)` many times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call gallery: this will just initialize DB1 to a specific sparse tridiagonal matrix, which you manually overwrite afterwards. With `n=100`, I suspect that you don't actually want to work on sparse matrices. Here's the solution:

```
epsilon = 0.45; t = -3.033;
n = 100;
DB1 = zeros(n); %initialize to 0

%diagonal indices
inds=sub2ind([n n],1:n,1:n);
DB1(inds) = epsilon;

%superdiagonal
inds=sub2ind([n n],1:n-1,2:n);
DB1(inds) = t*heaviside((-1).^(2:n));

%subdiagonal
inds=sub2ind([n n],2:n,1:n-1);
DB1(inds) = t*heaviside((-1).^(2:n));
```

Here `sub2ind` lets you compute linear indices from your matrix indices, allowing you to access "subvectors" in your matrix. Watch out for the exponentialization in the `heaviside`: you need `.^` instead of `^` to perform an element-wise operation using the vector `2:n`.

If you insist on getting a sparse matrix, you could either convert this matrix to sparse by calling

```
DB1=sparse(DB1);
```

which is the easiest option if your matrix is small. If `n` was larger and you would really need sparse matrices, then you could set up the sparse matrix itself by

```
DB1new=sparse([1:n 1:n-1 2:n],[1:n 2:n 1:n-1],...
    [epsilon*ones(1,n) t*heaviside((-1).^(2:n)) t*heaviside((-1).^(2:n))],n,n);
```

This call sets the elements of `DB1new` one-by-one according to its vector arguments: it takes the first index from the first input argument, the seconf index from the second, and the corresponding element from the third vector (see `help sparse` in MATLAB).

As for your second question: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Like in my example, `sub2ind` can be used to transform the multidimensional indices into linear ones, see `help sub2ind`. But personally, I think using the array notation is far more transparent and less prone to typos. And I think you can't vectorize that loop: you have to explicitly calculate the inverse matrix for each `k`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's so helpful to me.

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you feel that I answered your question, please mark it as accepted.